# Django can't map url to view using include method

Tags: python, django

I have the following urls.py in my project dir,

**Main project urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.render_calculator, name='render_calculator'),
    path('calculator/', views.render_calculator, name='render_calculator'),
    path('disclaimer/', views.render_disclaimer, name='render_disclaimer'),
    path('cookiepolicy/', views.render_cookiepolicy, name='render_cookiepolicy'),
    path('privacypolicy/', views.render_privacypolicy, name='render_privacypolicy'),
    path('dashboard/', views.render_dashboard, name='render_dashboard'),
    path('about/', views.render_about, name='render_about'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^', include('accounts.urls'))
]
```

Now I created a new app `accounts` (I added it to my apps in settings.py)  where I would like to store the urls of that app in its own dir like so:

**Accounts app urls.py**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.render_register, name='render_register'),
]
```

**Accounts app views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def render_register(request, template="register.html"):
    return render(request, template)
```

However, this configuration throws me this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register
Using the URLconf defined in CFD.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='render_calculator']
calculator/ [name='render_calculator']
disclaimer/ [name='render_disclaimer']
cookiepolicy/ [name='render_cookiepolicy']
privacypolicy/ [name='render_privacypolicy']
dashboard/ [name='render_dashboard']
about/ [name='render_about']
admin/
^
The current path, register, didn't match any of these.
```

Where is the missing piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `path()` with the regex `r'^'` which is causing your problem.

In order to define a path with a regex, you need to use [re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path).

So change it to the following line:

```py
    re_path(r'^', include('accounts.urls'))
```

or you can use

```py
    path('', include('accounts.urls'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this.

`path(r'^', include('accounts.urls'))` to

`path('', include('accounts.urls'))`